# SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312

Tags: c#, iis, openssl, http.sys

I'm building a C# console app that'll:

**[1.] Generate a self-signed certificate.**

**[2.] Add it to the Personal (Local Computer Store)**

**[3.] And finally assign that certificate to a port number on the machine with the netsh command.**

So far, I got parts **[1.]** and **[2.]** working perfectly, but on **[3.]** I'm plagued with the useless and non-informal error message:

> SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312 A specified logon session does
>   not exist. It may already have been terminated.

When I go look at Microsoft's official page about this issue:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/981506

It's basically telling me that this is a Windows Operating System bug and that I should request a hotfix.

**My Hack Solution To This Problem:**

One way I was able to finally bypass this error, was by Opening IIS Home>Open "Server Certificates" Feature> And then Importing my .pfx certificate.

By importing the .pfx to IIS, I seemed to be able to get around the issue without trouble. I only needed to generate a .pfx by running both these two commands in order

1.) `C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -subj "/C=US/ST=Denial/L=Springfield/O=Dis/CN=www.example.com" -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out certificate.crt`

2.) `C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -passout pass:`

So if I run those two commands to openssl right now, and import them via IIS to my Personal Local Computer certificate store, I'll have no `SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312` problem.

But if I add the newly generated certificate programatically to my Personal Local Computer certificate store, then I do get the Error:1312 problem.

Here's my code:

```
using CERTENROLLLib;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Generate_X509_Certificate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Launch OpenSSL:
            string cPath = @"C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\";
            string filename = Path.Combine(cPath, @"openssl.exe");

            // Generate a .crt file
            Console.WriteLine(@"Generating SSL Certificate...");
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe", @"req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out certificate.crt -subj ""/C=US/ST=California/L=SanFrancisco/CN=SecurityEncryption""");
            Process.Start(startInfo);

            // Combine the .crt with the .key to form a more Windows friendly .pfx
            Console.WriteLine(@"Combining Private Key With Certificate...");
            Process proc2 = Process.Start(filename, "pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -passout pass:");
            proc2.Close();

            // Store our newly created .pfx file as a variable
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+@"\cert.pfx");

            // Add our .pfx file into the Personal Local Computer store:
            var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            store.Add(cert);
            store.Close();

            // Finally, use netsh to assign this newly generated certificate to port 6613
            string s1 = "netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:6613 certhash=‎‎‎" + cert.GetCertHashString() + " appid={" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "}";
            Process p1 = new Process();
            p1.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
            p1.StartInfo.Arguments = s1;
            p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            //  this is where I get the error "SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312"
            p1.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the netsh command that works perfectly fine as long as I'm not executing it in this C# program:

> netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:6613
>   certhash=‎‎‎‎8834efd403687b331363ce9e5657ba4ffba0075b
>   appid={e604f84f-e666-4ccf-af52-fdeca666b5e9}

**The Confusing Part**

So if you were to execute my `openssl` commands verbatim from this thread, than import the `.pfx` file generated by openssl into IIS and finally use the `netssh` command as seen above with the proper certificate hash, than this entire thing works perfectly. But when you do what I just said automatically in the C# code above, I get the Error.

Another thing, the .pfx generated than imported into the store from this code will not work at all when you try to manually `netsh` it through the command line.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to run netsh in code, as PInvoking HTTP API is much easier.

Answer (score 6):

try explicit include the pfx to the cert before store it if using C#

```
    var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    //ensure pfx in cert.
    byte[] pfx = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx);
    cert = new X509Certificate2(pfx, (string)null, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

    //then store
    store.Add(cert);
    store.Close();
```

Comment: this solution did work for me :) saved my day. Thanks. The second parameter for X509Certificate2 is "password".